# Hooks for many hypotheses or conclusions

Tags: cases, hooks

Good morning!

How can I do this?

[image]

Thank's a lot!!!

**EDIT**

The below answer has this problem:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
  \text{If}\Rightarrow
  \begin{cases}
    \text{Conclusion }1, & a=1\\
    \text{Conclusion }2, & a=2\\
    \text{Conclusion }3, & a=3
  \end{cases}
\end{displaymath}
\begin{displaymath}
  \left.
    \begin{array}{@{}r@{}}
      \text{If }1\\
      \text{If }2\\
      \text{Longif }3
    \end{array}
  \right\}
  \Rightarrow\text{Conclusion}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

To have the cases in an `itemize` as described in the question edit, use `$...$` instead of displayed equation. However, I am not sure it is a good idea to have this type of case brackets in an itemization, it looks a bit strange.

```
\begin{itemize}
\item If $\Rightarrow$ Conclusion
\item $\left.
    \begin{array}{@{}r@{}}
      \text{If }1\\
      \text{If }2\\
      \text{Longif }3
    \end{array}
  \right\}
  \Rightarrow\text{Conclusion}$
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems very good, but I have problem with itemize.

Comment: @ΚώσταςΚούδας You can use a minipage in before the brace. See edit.

Comment: I 'm sorry... I didn't explain it well. I have problem when it is part of itemizing, as you can see at my edited answer.

Comment: @ΚώσταςΚούδας I have changed the edit.

Comment: Thank's a lot! You are right about the strange looking of cases in itemization. I 'm thinking about it! Thank's!!!